# Charset in Java returns UTF-8 but the chars are in Windows-1252

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, jboss

I have a Java application deployed in a Jboss Server. I have a problem with the "€" symbol (and I think others one)
In my local enviroment,I don't have this problem but in the development enviroment. 
I have a jsp, with the charset & encoding in UTF-8. I have a Jboss with this properties set:

```
client.encoding.override="UTF8"
org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING="true"
```

I have a filter in my source with:

```
servletRequest.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
servletResponse.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

And If I deploy my solution, this instruction returns "UTF8"

```
Charset.defaultCharset().displayName()
```

But when I send the "€" symbol, the request is:
value=0%E2%82%AC

Everything seems OK, but the char that print the output is:
0**â‚¬**

The char is encoded in Windows-1252

With this instruction, everythings is ok:

```
 String out = new String(mvp.getBytes(Charset.forName("Windows-1252")), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

But I need to know how could be the problem.Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] to show the code or explain how you get the value of mvp from 0%E2%82%AC.

Comment: `%E2%82%AC` is the proper UTF-8 url-encoding of the `€` character.  `â‚¬` means that url is being decoded to byte octets that are being processed as Windows-1252 instead of as UTF-8. So where is `mvp` coming from exactly? That is what you need to fix, not work around it after the fact, so that the UTF-8 is processed correctly and `mvp` is given to you as `"€"` instead of as `"â‚¬" to begin with.